# Is it possible to use css like media queries in javascript?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I am wondering if there is a way to use media queries in *javascript* like i use it in CSS ?
i want to handle *device-width* or *orientation* and fire a function .

now i am using this code :

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    /* test for various sizes */
};
```

but it is no good for me , i don't know how to make it work .

i need it to work in latest chrome without third parity libraries , i'm not sure if it is possible .

Comment: What's wrong with libraries?

Comment: we are not allowed to use third parity libraries in current project . it needs to be very light .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `window.matchMedia` method , wich allows you to test for a particular media query and add an event listener whenever it's matched or not .

Example :

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");
mq.addListener(function(event){
    if (event.matches) {
        console.log("Small Screen mode !");
    }
});
```

Example 2:

```
onOrientationChange = function(event){
    if (event.matches) {
        console.log("Portrait mode!");
    }
};

var mq = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
mq.addListener(onOrientationChange);

/* ... /*

/* When you no longer need to receive notifications , you can remove the listener */

mq.removeListener(onOrientationChange);
```

This API is supported in : Chrome 9+ , Firefox 6+ , IE10+

Additional info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Responsive JavaScript](http://www.responsivejavascript.com/). Sounds like it will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use matchMedia (jQuery)

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at least 500px
    }
    else {
        // window width is less than 500px
    }

}
```